# Can I use ml/nlp to determine pattern in the type of usernames are generated?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a dataset which has first and last names along with their respective email ids. Some of the email ids follow a certain pattern such as:

Fn1 = John , Ln1 = Jacobs, eid1= jj@xyz.com

Fn2 = Emily , Ln2 = Queens, eid2= eq@pqr.com

Fn3 = Harry , Ln3 = Smith, eid3= hsm@abc.com

The content after @ has no importance for finding the pattern. I want to find out how many people follow a certain pattern and what is that pattern. Is it possible to do so using nlp and python?

EXTRA: To know what kind of pattern is for a some number of people we can store examples of that pattern along with its count in an excel sheet?!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could - e.g., you could try to learn a relationship between your input and output data as

```
(Fn, Ln) --> eid
```

and further disect this relationship into patterns.

However before hitting the problem with complex tools (especially if new to ml/nlp), I'd do further analysis of the data first.

For example, I'd first be curious to see what portion of your data displays the clear patterns you've shown in the examples - using first character(s) from the individual's first/last name to build the corresponding eid  (which could be determined easily programatically).

Setting aside that portion of the data that satisfies this clear pattern - what does the remainder look like?

Is there are another clear, but different pattern to some of this data?

If there is - I'd then perform the same exercise again - construct a proper filter to collect and set aside data satisfying that pattern - and examine the remainder.

Doing this analysis might help determine at least a partial answer to your inquiry rather quickly

```
To know what kind of pattern is for a some number of people we can store examples of that pattern along with its count in an excel sheet?!
```

Moreover it will help determine

a) whether you need to even use more complex tooling (if enough patterns can be easily seived out this way - is it worth the investment to go heavier?) or

b) if not, which portion of the data to target with heavier tools (the remainder of this process - those not containing simple patterns).